# How to track the column value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I infer that a particular row in a table has been modified, how to find the set of columns I prefer is been modified.

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    RollID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Class NVARCHAR(100),
    age  INT,
    Address NVARCHAR(200)
)
```

In this case I'm interested to note whether the `(Name,Class)` has been modified

Comment: I want to update the modified columns in different db , probably datamart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx) is a feature in SQL Server 2008 that might be useful to you for implementing this.  I'm not sure it works against temporary tables as you have in your example, however.  If you are using permanent tables this is a powerful and useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an update trigger for that.

In that trigger you could find the column that was changed and if it is of interest react on it. For instance you could write in an extra table with timestamp and user info who changed the data.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, i want to select the modified rows and insert those rows in different db, probably after the modification was done at that time